# java.lang.IllegalStateException for Android version 4.4.4

Tags: java, android, listview, android-adapter

I am working with `adapters` in Android and in rare scenario's the app is crashing while setting data for `ListView`...Please Help out.
The Exception is as follows

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The content of the adapter has 
    changed but ListView did not receive a notification. Make sure the content of your 
    adapter is not modified from a background thread, but only from the UI thread.
     Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes.
     [in ListView(2131558745, class android.widget.ListView)
     with Adapter(class com.adapters.CustomToBeSyncAdapter)
```

Here is My code snippet

```
private class ImportAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Integer> {

                @Override
                protected Integer doInBackground(Void... params) {
                    Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

                    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute(Realm realm) {
                            try {
                                RealmResults<AssetsActivitiesRealm> mResultsActivities = realm.where(AssetsActivitiesRealm.class).findAll();
                                for (int i = 0; i < mResultsActivities.size(); i++) {
                                    AssetsActivitiesRealm mAssetsActivitiePj = mResultsActivities.get(i);
                                        SyncPojoList.add(new SyncPojo(mAssetsActivitiePj.getBatch(), mAssetsActivitiePj.getItemCode()));
                                }
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                    realm.close();
                    return 1;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    showLoading();
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Integer sum) {
                    try {
                        cancelLoading();
                        displayListView();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            private void notifyAdapter() {
                getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        listViewSync.setAdapter(null);
                        if (mdataAdapter != null) {
                            mdataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            listViewSync.requestLayout();
                        }
                    }
                });
            }

            private void displayListView() {
                    mdataAdapter = new CustomToBeSyncAdapter(getActivity(),
                            R.layout.custom_tobesync_row, SyncPojoList);
                    notifyAdapter();
                    listViewSync.setAdapter(mdataAdapter);
                    listViewSync.invalidate();
            }
```

Comment: *Make sure your adapter calls notifyDataSetChanged() when its content changes* - please try to apply `notifyDataSetChanged()` to ListView to notify it of background changes.

Comment: yes I have called notifyDataSetChanged() but still in rare case it crashes.. dont know how to fix this bug

Comment: Post the exact Logcat and Code when crash occurs, use http://hastebin.com

Comment: added logcat trace here https://gist.github.com/anonymous/016cbc8481944cb93ae52d8ab18ce904

Comment: try `notifyitemchanged()` and `notifyItemInserted()` it seems ViewPager is catching(changing ListView) before ListView is loaded.

Comment: only notify(), notifyall() and notifyDataSetInvalidated() methods available for adapter

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124152/discussion-between-deepak-and-rupinderjeet47).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're adding objects inside the `AsyncTask#doInBackground()` you're still changing the model of the `ListView`'s adapter from a background thread.

Try using the `AsyncTask#publishProgress(Progress...)` inside your `for-loop` and then override `AsyncTask#onProgressUpdate(Progress...)` where `Progress` is your model.

So your `for-loop` could look something like this:

```
RealmResults<AssetsActivitiesRealm> mResultsActivities = realm.where(AssetsActivitiesRealm.class).findAll();
for (int i = 0; i < mResultsActivities.size(); i++) {
    AssetsActivitiesRealm mAssetsActivitiePj = mResultsActivities.get(i);
    publishProgress(new SyncPojo(mAssetsActivitiePj.getBatch(), mAssetsActivitiePj.getItemCode());
}
```

And your `onProgressUpdate` could look like this:

```
public void onProgressUpdate(SyncPojo progress) {
    SyncPojoList.add(progress);
    mdataAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // Notifying changes to the adapter here.
}
```

It's not clear why you need to run all of this inside an `AsyncTask` and Realm actually advertises that you don't really need to run queries inside a background thread, as their querying is so fast (they're using lazy-loading when getting data) that it should affect the UI thread in most cases - especially when you don't have any "special" queries at all.

On another note, you don't need to create a `Realm.Transaction` to query the data. Transactions are only used to ensure correctness when changing data.

You could definitely simplify your code a lot:

- You're using `requestLayout` on your `ListView` after calling `notifyDatasetChanged` which is probably useless.
- You're using general `try-catch` with `Exception` for what reason? You should handle the code before it can lead to an exception instead of just adding a `try-catch` around the error prone code.
- Your `AsyncTask` returns a meaningless integer instead of actually returning the result for instance.
- setting the adapter will also notify the `ListView` to be updated, so no need to call your `notifyAdapter`.
- The `notifyAdapter` method is doing a lot of things, that it doesn't need to do - setting the adapter to `null` for instance.

Hope this helps, else I'll be happy to elaborate on any areas.

Comment: if i don't use Realm executeTransaction for loading data, UI freezes specially the progress bar..and I am going to use the same peace of code as you suggested and let you know.. :)

Comment: it seems a bug in this version https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=71936

Comment: @Deepak: What is this line of code doing specifically: `SyncPojoList.add(new SyncPojo(mAssetsActivitiePj.getBatch(), mAssetsActivitiePj.getItemCode()));`?

Comment: sir : adding ArrayList(SyncPojoList) from SyncPojo(pojo) class

Comment: @Deepak But if you're adding to an ArrayList from a background thread and the ArrayList is used as the model for your Adapter then this is definitely the issue. You are still modifying the data from outside of the UI thread as the exception tells you.

Comment: adding Arraylist in onProgressUpdate did the trick..till now i did not find any crash..@Darwind Thanks a ton.

Comment: @Deepak happy that I could help :-)